# sharepoint and other localhost sites, on port 80

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7, localhost, port80

i'm running sharepoint 2010 foundation, on win7.  since installing SP2010, none of my other localhost websites load in the browser. i'm either prompted for a login, or it just returns blank pages.  i've tried putting my other websites within the SP-80 directory in iis7, which allowed the pages to load, but required a login. i tried various combinations of windows authentication on different iis7 directories, but nothing worked. i'm left with the impression that iis7 requires a single port 80 directory, rather than distinct, named directors, with separate permissions. the issue could be complicated by having my other sites mapped to a virtual directory, requiring my admin creds, to allow iis access to the files.

my question is, is it possible to host public, unprotected, port 80, web sites, along with SP2010?  i'm not very experienced with IIS, so please forgive me if i'm overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

sure it is possible. While creating WebApplications in SharePoint you're able to specify the port, the WebApplication will run on.

You should have a look at your Site Settings within IIS. SharePoint is by default not running on anonymous authentication mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please analyze if you do have site collections created under Web Application using Powershell or from Central Admin

If you have Web Application created but no Site Collections, then you will get same issue

Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

If you want other sites on IIS on the same port on the same machine, you'll need to declare IIS host headers. When you create a new Site in IIS, there is a bindings section (IIS 7.5 - in IIS6, I believe it's just called Host Headers) - set your bindings to be myotherwebsite.com or myotherwebsite.local. Make sure the names you use in your bindings match DNS names that are pointing to that machine, either through public DNS (if it's a public site) or through your local hosts file (\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) if it's only for your local use.

Going the host headers route, you bypass the sharepoint execution stream completely - set your site up just as you would any other.